# How to refresh A Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been studying Android on Eclipse Mars for some time and i have been facing a constant problem everyday-the changes made in a folder/file are not recognized by some other folder/file. For example, if i create a new layout in the layout folder and then use it in the setContentView, it shows me an error ("layout-name cannot be resolved or is not a field). It works if i save the project,close it, and open it again, but this takes up a lot of time if i have more than one error, so the question-is there a way to save and refresh the project (without having to close it) so that the newly made files and folders are recognized by the java files?
Thank you.

Comment: side note, and not really an answer: Eclipse is now deprecated for android dev, Android Studio is the currently supported IDE. It may work better.

Comment: @njzk2 oh, if that's the case, I'll see to it then.
Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @njzk2, completely agree with you, Android Studio would be better if  you are new

Comment: Eclipse sure had a refresh button somewhere, be careful if you plan to port your project to Android Studio, maybe its even easier to create a new one and copy the code.

Comment: Android Studio is the best IDE I've used so far.  Use it not Eclipse..

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh your project in Eclipse by right clicking on the project root folder in your Project Explorer and selecting "Refresh".

You may also want to consider checking if you have "auto build project" turned on. In your top toolbar go to  Project -> Build Automatically.

If build automatically is turned off you will have to manually build your project, by Right Clicking on the project in your Project Explorer and selecting "Build Project".

However,  I do agree with Pankaj Nimgade that Android Studio is likely a better entry point IDE for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Real advice: Switch to Android Studio as soon as you can. There you would  sometimes have another problem called "sync" though. But it's a much better IDE and you are at least in line with Google.

on Eclipse, F5 should do the trick. Or right click your project and Refresh. Or Clean all projects. If you are still stuck, simply close Eclipse and run it again.